# nginx returns blank page

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

i have a php api running in docker, i want to setup a reverse proxy using nginx  on my host. currently, when i visit mydomain.com/doc i get a blank screen but if i try with my server's ip address 111.111.11:8000/doc it works fine. Also, if i use mydomain.com:8000/doc it also works fine. i would like to access it via mydomain.com/doc.
my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    

        location /doc {
                proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:8000/doc;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/php-error.log info;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }

}
```

i want my domain accessible via domain.com/doc

Answer (score 1):

It's because you did it wrong, you need to add another `/` in your location and at the end of your proxy url so it uses your website directory.
Also use `127.0.0.1` for your proxy.

```
server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    

        location /doc/ {
                proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:8000/doc/;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/php-error.log info;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see a misunderstanding with with the `0.0.0.0` ip

`0.0.0.0` is only usable for listing because it means "listen to all IPv4", in contrast to `127.0.0.1` which means "only listen to 127.0.0.1". But you can not use it to connect to something, it is not a routable IP.

Example nginx config with the IP issue fixed. I have also removed the `doc` parts, it is redundant and only needed if you really depend on an extra location block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/php-error.log info;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```